# trying to use jython with android studio

Tags: python, java, android, android-studio, jython

I am trying to use jython in my java app for android but I'm having trouble building the project with the .jar file.

here is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.ytdownloader'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ytdownloader"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/jython-standalone-2.7.3.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

but I am getting this error

```
com.android.tools.r8.internal.k2: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)
```

before adding the jython .jar file and adding this dependency, the app would build fine which makes me think it is a problem with the .jar.

has anyone come across this error before? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think Jython is compatible with Android and DEX. Furthermore Jython only supports Python2 and thus is deprecated/EOL, you should not start a new project using a dead horse...

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error and I have solution of this error you are using min SDK 21 in your project.

```
minSdk 21
```

change it to 26 or more than 26 error will resolve

```
minSdk 26
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).